# Stop facebook using featured image for blog sharing

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

When I share a blog post from wordpress, WP defaults to the post's featured image and doesn't offer any options to select another image from within the post. I need to stop fb seeing the featured image as it's irrelevant to the share, and allow it to scrape the page for other images.

The code within my blog post head is as follows:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_fbimage(); ?>"/>
```

and the function is:

```
        function get_fbimage() {
      $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '', '' );
      if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
        $fbimage = $src[0];
      } else {
        global $post, $posts;
        $fbimage = '';
        $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',
        $post->post_content, $matches);
        $fbimage = $matches [1] [0];
      }
      if(empty($fbimage)) {
        $fbimage = "";
      }

  return $fbimage;
}
```

Any advice is greatly received

Comment: I don't know if this will directly answer your question but there is a Facebook debugging tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ which reads in a URL, shows you what it's picking up and offers (some) information on why it's reaching the conclusions it is. 

I discovered that I needed to change my image dimensions to get my intended image noted as the shared one.

Preventing Facebook from seeing an Open Graph-stipulated image may not be possible, though, as it's heavily signed up to the OG format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That meta tag is telling Facebook to specifically use your featured image. If you don't want that image specifically and want FB to try to choose another (or present a list of available images), remove that meta tag completely. Then, FB will start scraping the page when it's shared.

Facebook caches your site so it may take a while (hours to days) for you to see the change in future shared posts.